# Two different Unix timestamp returns same date/time using moment.js

Tags: timestamp, momentjs

I was trying to get date/time from Unix timestamp. But why two different timestamps returned the same date/time:

moment.unix(1561514760).format("M/D/YYYY HH:MM:SS ZZ");

returned
"6/25/2019 19:06:00 -0700"

moment.unix(1561517978).format("M/D/YYYY HH:MM:SS ZZ");

returned
"6/25/2019 19:06:00 -0700"

But if I ran
moment("6/25/2019 19:06:00 -0700").unix();
will only get 1561514760
My UTC time zone is -7:00 and I ran the code in my browser console.

Comment: I tried on Safari Version 12.1.1 (14607.2.6.1.1) and Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit) .  Both are the same confusing return

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Recommend you [edit] your question to include that info so it isn't buried in the comments.  It will help people trying to help you as well as future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting tokens are case sensitive.

You are getting the same values because `MM` is for the month (which is `06` in both cases), and `SS` is fractional seconds (which is `00` in both cases).

You should use `mm` for minutes, and `ss` for seconds instead.

Also:

> ... My UTC time zone is -7:00 ...

Be careful about terminology.  The only "UTC time zone" is UTC itself, and some would argue UTC isn't a time zone at all.  Instead, The "offset from UTC" for your "local time zone" is -07:00 *for the timestamp given*.  See also "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Also note that if you would rather display the UTC time rather than your local time, then you can do:

```
moment.unix(<the timestamp>).utc().format(<your format string>)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Matt.  It worked beautifully.  Actually, I want to momen.js to get a local date/time info by giving Unix timestamp and time zone.  How can I do this directly?  Now I have to display UTC time (apply timeoffset) and manually add time zone.

Comment: Please be more specific, and if not what you asked originally, then please don't chain on questions.  Ask a new question - or better yet, search to see if that question has been asked before.